# Extend a vectors to the basis (Do I have mistake or missunderstanding?)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I can't find a mistake in my calculus. So I have

$U:=\{p \in \mathbb P_4(\mathbb R):p(6)=0\}$.

I found the basis $((x-6),(x^2-6x),(x^3-6x^2),(x^4-6x^3))$. Now I have to extend it to basis of $\mathbb P_4(\mathbb R)$. The solution is take $W:=\{1\}$.

But I want to check for practice, whether $x \in$ span$((x-6),(x^2-6x),(x^3-6x^2),(x^4-6x^3))$. Because if not, I have to extend my basis by $x$. I started with:

$a(x-6)+b(x^2-6x)+c(x^3-6x^2)+d(x^4-6x^3)=x \iff$

$ax-6a+bx^2-6bx+cx^3-6cx^2+dx^4-6dx^3=x \iff$

$-6a+x(a-6b)+x^2(b-6c)+x^3(c-6d)+x^4d=x$

By comparing the coefficients on both side, we get:

$-6a=0$

$a-6b=1$

$b-6c=0$

$c-6d=0$

$d=0$,

so I get $d=c=b=0$ from the first equation I know that $a=0$, therefore $a-6b=1$ can not be. So I proved, that $x \notin$ span$((x-6),(x^2-6x),(x^3-6x^2),(x^4-6x^3))$. The same situation with $1$. $1$ is also $\notin$ span$((x-6),(x^2-6x),(x^3-6x^2),(x^4-6x^3))$. Why should I extend my basis $((x-6),(x^2-6x),(x^3-6x^2),(x^4-6x^3))$ by $1$ to get basis of $\mathbb P_4(\mathbb R)$, and not by $x$, since $x$ is also not in span?

Did I have mistake somewhere? Can somebody explain me it, please?

Comment: “Take $W:=\{1\}$”: what is W?

Comment: @FShrike $W$ is set with only $1$ inside.

Comment: … “the solution is to take $W=\{1\}$” doesn’t mean anything unless you identify the role of $W$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the set $\{x-6, x(x-6), x^2(x-6), x^3(x-6)\}$ by **any** polynomial $p$ such that $p(6) \ne 0$ will produce a basis of $\mathbb P_4(\mathbb R)$. This means that $1$ will work, and $x$ will work, and $x^2+x^3+x^4$ will work, and many other options.

The argument is: suppose you want to write a polynomial $q$ in the basis $\{x-6, x(x-6), x^2(x-6), x^3(x-6), p\}$, where $p\in P_4(\mathbb R)$ is an arbitrary polynomial such that $p(6) \ne 0$. Then let $a = \frac{q(6)}{p(6)}$; since $p(6) \ne 0$, this division is okay! We have $q(6) - ap(6) = 0$, so $q-ap$ is in the subspace $U$, and therefore $q-ap$ can be written as a linear combination of the other basis vectors. This gives us a representation of $q$.

In general, you should not expect there to be just one solution to the problem of "how do I extend this linearly independent set to be a basis?"

Comment: Thank you, Misha! I am very grateful! I have some questions to your argument, if you have time, couldn't you answer? In this set $\{x-6, x(x-6), x^2(x-6), x^3(x-6), p\}$ what is p? Which polynomial $p$ are you talking about? It's $p \in U$ isn't? And why $a=\frac{q(6)}{p(6)}$ is so defined? By which assumption? In any case, you helped me very much) ( Nikita )

Comment: Here, $p$ is the arbitrary polynomial we picked for which $p(6) \ne 0$. And $a = \frac{q(6)}{p(6)}$ is defined by exactly that assumption: $p(6) \ne 0$, so we can divide by it. (I've edited my answer to be more clear about this.)

Comment: I got it) thank you)